# Trying to get started with LISA and Lisp

Tags: expert-systems, lisp

I am trying to to do a sort of block-validator for bitcoin(and alike chains), in it I need to depending on chain and block-height only allow certain operators in the transactions scripts. One thought I had was that this might be something that LISA should be good for. (I might be wrong in this) but shouldn't something like a rule engine be a good fit for that? What I want is a good way to defines the rules for my validator on how to validate that a block and its transactions adhere to the consensus rules?

I am sort of getting to this point

```
(defpackage #:chain-validator
  (:shadowing-import-from #:lisa #:assert)
  (:use #:lisa
    #:cl))

(in-package :chain-validator)

(defclass chain-fundamental () ())

(defclass chain-block (chain-fundamental)
  ((height :initarg :height :initform 1)
   (chain :initarg :chain :initform :bitcoin)))

(defclass chain-tx (chain-fundamental)
  ((in-block :initarg :block :initform 'nil)
   (pk-script :initarg :pk-script)
   (is-coinbase-tx :initarg :coinbase :initform 'f)))

(defclass chain-OP (chain-fundamental)
  ((name :initarg :name)
   (op-code :initarg :op-code)))

(defrule dont-allow-op-mul-after-height-1000
    ;;; how to write this one?????
    ;; but if I only want to allow mul on a certain chain after height
    ;; 2000?
    )

(defrule startup ()
  =>
  (assert-instance
   (make-instance 'chain-OP :name :PUSHDATA4 :op-code #x4e))
  (assert-instance
   (make-instance 'chain-OP :name :EQUAL :op-code #x87))
  (assert-instance
   (make-instance 'chain-OP :name :MUL :op-code #x95))
  (let* ((genesis-blk (make-instance 'chain-block))
     (later-blk (make-instance 'chain-block :height 2500))
     (first-coinbase-tx (make-instance 'chain-tx :block genesis-blk))
     (later-coinbase-tx (make-instance 'chain-tx :block later-blk)))
    (assert-instance genesis-blk)
    (assert-instance later-blk)
    (assert-instance first-coinbase-tx)
    (assert-instance later-coinbase-tx)))


;; how can I use LISA to get the chain-OPs that are allowed for a
;; transaction belonging to a specific block at some height, I sort of
;; want to find them all so i later can verify that the pk-script part
;; only contains those OPs. Could I write rules that would acctually
;; do the validation for me? that would check if chain-tx.pk-script
;; only contains certain OPs. And if we have multiple chains, how do I
;; write the rules to take account for that?
```

But after that I don't know how to proceed, the questions I want LISA to answer for me are things like

- What are the valid script operations for a certain block, or transaction?
- Is this block or transaction valid?

Maybe what I need is primer on rule engines or a good tutorial. I just can't really get my head around how to write the rules.